# Получение time_t из строки содержащей время в текстовом формате

Tags: c++

Есть строка вида `Wed, 10 Oct 2018 01:15:33 GMT`

Какой функцией можно преобразовать ее в `time_t` значение

Comment: Написанной самостоятельно...

Answer (score 0):

Unix-way

```
const char *time_details = "16:35:12";
struct tm tm;
strptime(time_details, "%H:%M:%S", &tm);
time_t t = mktime(&tm);
```

Windows-way

```
std::string startTime = "2016/05/18 13:10:00";

time_t tStart;
int yy, month, dd, hh, mm, ss;
struct tm whenStart;
const char *zStart = startTime.c_str();

sscanf(zStart, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d", &yy, &month, &dd, &hh, &mm, &ss);
whenStart.tm_year = yy - 1900;
whenStart.tm_mon = month - 1;
whenStart.tm_mday = dd;
whenStart.tm_hour = hh;
whenStart.tm_min = mm;
whenStart.tm_sec = ss;
whenStart.tm_isdst = -1;

tStart = mktime(&whenStart);

std::cout << tStart << std::endl;
```